# How can I make a join using two model classes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two model classes:

**Empresa:**

```
 public class Empresa
 {
        public int EmpresaId { get; set;}
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
 }
```

**Funcionario**

```
 public class Funcionario
 {
        public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cargo { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key
        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
        public Empresa Empresas { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `EmpresaController` that have a method get that return all data from `Empresa`:

```
//GET: api/empresa
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Empresa>>> getEmpresas()
{
    return await _context.Empresa.ToListAsync();
}
```

I need to make the result of this query in entity framework, how i can do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Empresa e
JOIN Funcionario f ON (e.EmpresaId = f.EmpresaId)
```

**@Edit:**

Malformed json:

[errorjson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVi8M.png)

I think is missing }]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use an include to achieve what you want (it performs a join internally)

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Empresa>>> getEmpresas()
{
    var empresas =  await _context.Empresas.Include(t=> t.Funcionarios).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(empresas);
}
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework, or entity framework core?

Comment: Now i receive that i don't have a toList definition that accepts the argument "InncludableQueryable"

Comment: My actually function:         public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Empresa>>> getNome()
        {
            return await _context.Empresa.Include(t => t.Funcionarios).ToList();
        }

Comment: Okk I realized something is really wrong with your method, you're trying to return an entity directly from the action of the controller. That's not possible because your entity is not of type ActionResult. I'm gonna edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Ops, i'm getting a malformed json: "funcionarios":[{"funcionarioId":3,"nome":"Test","cargo":"TestJunior","salario":10850.0,"empresaId":1

Comment: What's wrong with that?. Maybe you don't want to return empresaId, if that's the case you should create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) and map the entity directly to the dto before returning it in the Ok method. (The Dto should contain only the fields you want to return)

Comment: Ok, now everything is working. I need to add this code in startup.cs:             services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; });

Comment: Great it works! you were just missing some configuration with the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Linq Join query

```
return await (from e in _context.Empresa
              join f in _context.Funcionario on e.EmpresaId equals f.EmpresaId
              select e).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I receive "Join" not found of origin type DbSet<Empresa>

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this relationship in your `DbContext` class as well.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        // your other code here
        builder.Entity<Funcionario>(entity => {
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Empresa)
                .WithMany(e => e.Funcionarios);
        });
        // rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: When i make a get the key in json "funcionarios" is null, but i have one record in this "empresa"